# Uncaught TypeError: with Redux Thunk and node.js express wwwhisper middleware on MERN stack application

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, wwwhisper

I am building a MERN stack application and trying to use the connect-`wwwhisper` package to protect access to an application (testing beta version) that I am hosting. I am using passport authentication on the Node js backend for user authentication but I want to layer `wwwhisper` package on entire app so that only people with approved email may access the entire app without disturbing the passport authentication that I set up.  I have set up `wwwhisper` per the documentation:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/wwwhisper  but there is a conflict with the redux thunk middleware that is causing a type error within the redux js file below:

```
    function compose() {
    for (var _len = arguments.length, funcs = new Array(_len), _key = 
    0; 
    _key < _len; _key++) {
    funcs[_key] = arguments[_key];
    }

    if (funcs.length === 0) {
    return function (arg) {
      return arg;
    };
    }

    if (funcs.length === 1) {
    return funcs[0];
    }

    return funcs.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return function () {
      return a(b.apply(void 0, arguments));
```

The error message is:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

In my server js file I am using the following to direct requests to the index.html file of the react side of the application.  All other requests to the backend api are using the

```
    app.use("routename");

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      app.use(express.static("client/build"));
      app.get("*", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", 
      "index.html"));
     });
     }
```

The `wwwhisper` middleware does protect the application and sends out the tokenized link to access the application but when I try to access the application I get the above error message along with a message saying the token is unauthorized.  The author of the `wwwhisper` middleware is not familiar with how the `wwwhisper` middleware may be interacting with the Redux thunk middleware.  How can I get this to work?  I've been programming for about a year so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The wwwhisper add-on was recently updated and it now offers a buildpack that works with any language and framework supported by Heroku. Unlike the `connect-wwwhisper` middleware, the buildpack is run as a separate process that passes authorized requests to the application. This removes any potential interference or conflict between the application code and the wwwhisper code and solves the problems like the one that you have encountered with Redux.

A [Heroku devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/wwwhisper) article includes instructions how to enable the wwwhisper buildpack.